# Use repeat function in map alongside lambda function

Tags: python

I have a function named `tmp` that only returns two strings. In addition, I have 2 iterables that I want to pass to the `tmp` function, one of them has 88000 lengths and another one has 50 lengths. I want to change the second one on every 200 iterates, but the problem is I can not iterate over the second iterable. Here is what I've done so far.

Code:

```
from itertools import repeat


url_list = [] # contains over 80000 urls 
files = [] # contains 50 files

def tmp(url, file):
    return url, file
    
# I want to use the file for only 200 URLs and then change it and use the next one in the list(files) provided
list(map(tmp, url_list, map(lambda x: repeat(x, 200), files)))
```

Expected output:

```
url1, file1
url2, file1
url3, file1
.
.
url201, file2
url202, file2
.
.
.
url401 file3
url402 file3
.
.
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please show a small example of the sequence you want with iterables containing say 6 and 2 strings, respectively?

Comment: What output are you expecting (again, easier with a small example)? This is why constructing a [mcve] is so important.

Comment: Also, what is the problem with the code you have?

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for your response, I will edit the question and add an example.

Comment: `50 * 200` is only 10000. How will you use that with 88000 in the first iterable. Does it need to go back to the beginning of the second iterable?

Comment: That's not the problem @Barmar I will increase the number of files or just like you said I'll go back to the beginning of the second iterable.

Comment: I know it's not the problem you were asking about, I'm just asking for clarification of what you expect it to do. You'll need to use `cycle` to go back to the beginning.

Comment: `repeat` returns a list of lists. Try flattening that. `list(map(tmp, url_list, [f for ff in repeat(files, 200) for f in ff]))` Or `list(map(tmp, url_list, itertools.chain.from_iterable(repeat(files, 200))))`

Comment: I think for now I go with the second approach which means going back to the beginning of the second iterable.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than repeating `files` 200 times, split `url_list` into chunks of 200. See [How do I split a list into equally-sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-i-split-a-list-into-equally-sized-chunks) for various ways to code this.

Use `itertools.cycle()` to go back to the beginning of `files` when you reach the end.

```
result = []

for url_chunk, file in zip(chunks(url_list, 200), itertools.cycle(files)):
    result.extend([url, file for url in url_chunk])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try for example this:

```
import pprint

url_list = ["url" + str(i+1) for i in range(20)]
file_list = ["file" + str(i+1) for i in range(5)]
every_n = 3

result = [ (url_list[i], file_list[min(i // every_n, len(file_list)-1)])
           for i in range(len(url_list)) ]

pprint.pprint(result)
```

The output of above script:

```
[('url1', 'file1'),
 ('url2', 'file1'),
 ('url3', 'file1'),
 ('url4', 'file2'),
 ('url5', 'file2'),
 ('url6', 'file2'),
 ('url7', 'file3'),
 ('url8', 'file3'),
 ('url9', 'file3'),
 ('url10', 'file4'),
 ('url11', 'file4'),
 ('url12', 'file4'),
 ('url13', 'file5'),
 ('url14', 'file5'),
 ('url15', 'file5'),
 ('url16', 'file5'),
 ('url17', 'file5'),
 ('url18', 'file5'),
 ('url19', 'file5'),
 ('url20', 'file5')]
```

Remark:

- `//` integer division 5 // 2 = 2